# AzureDevops Pipeline issue error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I am having an issue with AzureDevops building a project. It's DotNet6, It's failing the .Net Core Restore with an error:  error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source.
It's a library project with two dependencies, both from NuGet:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions v2.2.0
- Stripe.net - 41.2.0

The project builds perfectly in VS2022.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite both packages (below) being #DotNetCore 6 compatible, the AzureDevops .NetCore Restore consistently failed.

I created a new pipeline using the NuGet command instead, and all was fine.

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions v2.2.0
- Stripe.net - 41.2.0

Comment: Hi @John McArthur, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue. You could also  [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), this will help other users who has the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving this error during the build step for an internal artifact on a single pipeline (but not others).  Adding this to my pipelines.yml resolved the issue for me:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true
```

Adding here though the original problem is slightly different I didn't find any one mentioning this as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the error information `error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source`, it seem like that pipeline couldn’t load the specific version packages from the feed you configured in your pipeline or project .
Here’re some suggestions to check your settings in your Azure DevOps.

1 check your  `NuGet.config` file in your project  if you select feeds in my Nuget.config and make sure the packageSources are correct.

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget" value=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json />
</packageSources>
```

2 check your packages version and make sure the version is available in nuget org.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include=" Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In addition, you can add full error information for further identifying the possible cause of the issue.

Comment: Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.